# Verify that compiler inlined object creation/method call

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Let's say I have a code like this:

```java
public class InlineTest {
    private String test() {
        return "test";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
          new InlineTest().test()
        );
    }
}
```

I know that Java HotSpot is smart enough to [inline](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#method) object creation and method call for `new InlineTest().test()`.

However I can't check if the inlining was really applied!

**Q 1:** Is it possible to verify inlining by inspecting **only** byte-code? How?

If it is not an option:

**Q 2:** Are there any other possibilities other than disassembler the code?

PS I have `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`.

Comment: Have you tried `-XX:+LogCompilation` and JITWatch? In my experience it is only in rare and strange corner cases that you need to dig into how things are compiled by JIT. (Excluding highly specialised software.) But it's fun to get into and play around with, even though its practical applications are few and far between.

Comment: @biziclop No, I haven't tried. I'll read about this option and try it tonight.

You're right, there is no practical need. I just want to understand deeper how it works.

Comment: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintInlining`

Comment: The method is inlined at runtime only after the code has been called many times e.g. 10,000 times. So you can be confident this hasn't been inlined.

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding byte code: there is **no** inlining on the byte code level.
Thus nothing that could be observed by de-assembling that byte code.

Regarding the JIT part: see [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-evans-pt1-2266278.html) for example (or [theree](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.win.80.doc/diag/understanding/jit_overview.html) for IBM java). But you have to understand that such things **depend** on the version of your JVM; as far as I know, there are no means that you could use to understand for all kinds of JVMs (Oracle, IBM, Azuul, ...) what exactly each implementation is doing under the covers.

And beyond that: keep in mind that the JIT is **highly dynamic**. It might **not** inline methods immediately, but maybe at a *later* point in time. The idea is that the JIT decides based on *runtime* data what kind of optimizations it is going to apply. The JIT might even come back and re-compile a method when it later finds that there could be a *better* sequence of machine instructions ...